# how to color text input in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

this is my user Form:

[image]

I have a problem, the color of  input field is white, and the background is same white.
I could not find anywhere How to change the color of input field.

What the attribute css for color texte  ?

this is my template :

```html
<div class="example-container" style="color:red">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Input">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Select">
        <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  new contact
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@J.S. is correct if you haven't included theme in your application, but if you are interested in customizing color properties of input field-

For changing the color of place-holder(in this case 'input') you can change 'color' of below class -

```
.mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label {
    color: green;
}
```

For changing the underline-color when it's highlighted-

```
.mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: green;
}
```

you will have to include this code piece in `styles.scss` (or `styles.css`).

Answer (score 20):

```
Here is some most common properties of angular material v7

/* input color class */
::ng-deep input.mat-input-element {
  color: #484a4c;
}

/* Change label color on focused */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: #50d0fb !important;
}

/* underline border color on focused */
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple{
  background-color: #50d0fb !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you applied a color theme to your project: [how to Include a theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme), e.g adding this into your styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Also important [Angular Material Theming Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Material decides, based on a color palette, which color should be applied. You can configure it like described in the links.

As last option you can overwrite styles (not recommended) using the css-selectors. You can debug your app in browser to get to know which css-selector to use. In your case I think you can use:

```
.mat-form-field
```

Or if that does not work use:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks ,
I would working with a custom css directly, I use less and visual studio compile css.

this is my `style.less`

```less
@import 'my.css';
```

I've forked my.css in the file:
`@angular\material\prebuilt-themes\purple-green.css`

```less
.mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label {
    background: green;
    color:purple;
}

.mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: green;
    color:blue;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field{
    color:red
}

//css @angular\material\prebuilt-themes\purple-green.css in at bottom...
```

This is the result:

[image: background ok but the text is white]

the text is not color purple , the background green is ok

Comment: Ok thank's , i input css in the top my fork file,the texte is not color purple beacause i must inject css at the buttom not the top(i forgot the css is crush the top my css) , thank's. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular .. 
add this in 'style.css'

```
 .mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label {
    color: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng::deep` disable view encapsulation for specific CSS rules, in other words, it gives you access to DOM elements, which are not in your component's HTML.

You will have to use it to select the form field

`::ng-deep .mat-form-field`